# Question mark or not?

Tags: question-mark

SHOULD THERE BE A QUESTION MARK OR NOT? IT'S AN INDIRECT QUESTION BUT AN ANSWER WOULD BE EXPECTED.

There's a party later if you're interested.

There's a party later if you're interested?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. For us to be able to help, please [edit] your post to explain what you intend the statement to mean, and why *you* think there should or should not be a question mark based on your understanding. Otherwise, we are just making guesses. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for guidance on asking strong questions. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: One other bit of advice: DON'T SHOUT, it's quite unnecessary and somewhat discourteous. Use **bold** instead: on our site you can make it bold by putting a double asterisk `**` on either side of the words you want to emphasise. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because it is a [declarative statement](https://www.thoughtco.com/declarative-sentence-grammar-1690420).

There should be a comma though.

> *There's a party later, if you're interested.*

Comment: Also, there should be no assumption that an answer is coming. One might simply respond, "Thanks for telling me".